# Error 16755 - Mongo can't extract geo keys

Tags: mongodb, geolocation

I'm a beginnen with mongo and node.js, and in a existing project we have a collection with shops with geolocs. I get the following error (I have removed some fields)

```
"code" : 16755,
"errmsg" : "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('566990eea9c7a38740a305a3'), 
id: 50, guid: \"NL7a09b334-7524-102d-a4ef-00163e5faa0c\", version: 0, owner: 118, 
published: 1, loc: [ -9999, -9999 ], logo: \"69db95d0-d58d-40cf-80d3-ac80b8c86af8.png\" }  
can't project geometry into spherical CRS: [ -9999, -9999 ]"
```

when I try to `$set` some values on the shop. I see that the values -9999, -9999 are not correct but when I try to replace that with (in Robomongo) other values I get the same error. How can I fix this error, so I can edit the values in `loc` and do a `$set`?

Comment: How does your update operation look like? please include it

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the error is because of the invalid geo coordinates you have in that document (see [2dsphere indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/2dsphere/)).

Assuming this is the document you have:

```
> db.test.find()

{
  "_id": ObjectId("566990eea9c7a38740a305a3"),
  "id": 50,
  "guid": "NL7a09b334-7524-102d-a4ef-00163e5faa0c",
  "version": 0,
  "owner": 118,
  "published": 1,
  "loc": [
    -9999,
    -9999
  ],
  "logo": "69db95d0-d58d-40cf-80d3-ac80b8c86af8.png"
}
```

The easiest method is to use the [`mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/mongo/) to [perform an update](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/), by using the `ObjectId` and do a [`$set` on the `loc` field](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/set/). For example, by setting the `loc` field to a valid coordinate (e.g. [-73.97, 40.77]):

```
> db.test.update({"_id": ObjectId("566990eea9c7a38740a305a3")}, {$set:{loc:[-73.97, 40.77]}})

Updated 1 existing record(s) in 1ms
WriteResult({
  "nMatched": 1,
  "nUpserted": 0,
  "nModified": 1
})
```

Note that in the example above, I'm using the `_id` field, which is guaranteed to be unique, so that the update command will only update that exact document. After that, your 2dsphere index creation should succeed:

```
> db.test.createIndex({loc:'2dsphere'})

{
  "createdCollectionAutomatically": false,
  "numIndexesBefore": 1,
  "numIndexesAfter": 2,
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but when I run `db.shop.update({_id: ObjectId('566990eea9c7a38740a305a3')}, {$set:{loc:[-73.97, 40.77]}})` I get the same error..

Comment: Did you use the `mongo` shell? I tested this query in the `mongo` shell. If you use RoboMongo to perform the update, there could be issues in RoboMongo that prevents you from doing the update.

Comment: Also, the index shouldn't be created with invalid values in the first place, and also shouldn't allow inserts with invalid values (i.e. that document should not be there if a `2dsphere` index exists on the `loc` field). If you still can't edit that document, it's probably best to drop and recreate the `2dsphere` index.